# #<FastJsonapi::MandatoryField: id is a mandatory field in the jsonapi spec>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, fastjsonapi

When trying to pass an enum object to serializer I get the following error:

`#<FastJsonapi::MandatoryField: id is a mandatory field in the jsonapi spec>`

`@drop_down_values = Organisation.ownerships`
where @drop_down_values has the enum values from ownership column.

`render json: DropDownValueSerializer.new(@drop_down_values).serialized_json`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out that `FastJsonAPI expects` object `id` by default. Hence, when passing object to `serializer` it expects `id` to be present in the object passed.

'https://github.com/Netflix/fast_jsonapi/issues/100'  this has been logged as an issue in FastJsonAPI.

The below works properly:

`render json: DropDownValueSerializer.new(Organisation.first).serialized_json`